# Need help C# textBox1.Text does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

```
        {
        if (("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller")) ;
        textBox1.Text = "Successfuly found XixanPackInstaller!";
    }
    else
        textBox1.Text = "Move XixanPackInstaller to your desktop!";
    }
```

I have this code and it's broken because at else on visual studio it says invalid token else and on textBox1.Text it says textBox1.text does not exist in the current context

Comment: and where is textBox1 declared? btw you might want to remove the `;` after `if (("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller")) ;`

Comment: we could get a better understanding if you provide the full method.

Comment: and this looks fishy as well: `(("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller"))` because you are comparing two constants that are unequal. you are basically saying: `if(0 == 1) { .... }`. I assume `zipPath` is a variable, so you should remove the quotes (ie. `if(zipPath.Equals("XixanPackInstaller")) { ... }`

Comment: @Benj: And the fact that the if doesn't have a statement or block following it either, just s `;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
        if (("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller")) //**;** also the semi-colon
        textBox1.Text = "Successfuly found XixanPackInstaller!";
    //}---please remove this bracket here
    else
        textBox1.Text = "Move XixanPackInstaller to your desktop!";
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: `("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller")`is always `false`

Answer (score 1):

You are better of using a Ternary Operator `?:` here like

```
textBox1.Text = ("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller") ?
   "Successfuly found XixanPackInstaller!" :
        "Move XixanPackInstaller to your desktop!";
```

Comment: `("zipPath" == "XixanPackInstaller")`is always `false`

Comment: @Benj, yes that's for sure. it was to show OP that ternary operator makes much more sense here cause the condition doesn't make any sense.